# Unable to trigger validation rule when blank

Tags: validation, validation-rule

We want a validation that if users changes the picklist values from previous values to blank or null, an error message should be displayed.

The vaidation rule which I had applied was :

```
OR(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Verification__c), "Reverification - Pass"), 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Verification__c), "Reverification - Fail") 
) 

&& 

( 
ISPICKVAL(Verification__c, ""))
```

and have added the error message as : you cannot change the verifiaction to blank once selected.

But this validation rule does not work.

Comment: try `&& ISBLANK(TEXT(Verification__c))`

Comment: Seems like a probable typo in your prior values.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
AND(ISCHANGED( Verification__c ),
    OR(
       ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Verification__c), "Reverification - Pass"),
       ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Verification__c), "Reverification - Fail"),
      ),
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Verification__c))
 )
```